# How to save user meta on custom admin page

Tags: options, user-meta

I have removed the edit profile page from WP admin as I don't want users to be able to edit their details as this is a closed intranet and their details are fed from AD.

However I do want them to be able to publish their own user description (Biography). So I've set out to add a new admin page to give the user the ability to do that:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'sc_stace_user_bio_page');
function sc_stace_user_bio_page() {
    $page = add_menu_page( "Your Biography", "Biography", "read", "user-bio", "sc_stace_user_bio_page_content", "", 50 );
}

function sc_stace_user_bio_page_content() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Your Biography</h2>
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="user_description"><?php echo esc_textarea($current_user->user_description); ?></textarea>
            <?php submit_button( "Save", "primary", "submit", true ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

As far as I know I cannot use the Settings API here as this info needs saving into the logged in users meta not into options table. So now I'm stuck as I don't know where the form should be saving to and how to check for form submission the correct way.

So where should I be submitted the form to? What nonces if any should I be putting in the form? What do I need to hook into for checking form submission and if correct data is being sent save to user's meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'description', $_POST['user_description']);
```

in the form processing function will save the bio.

I would keep the form action on the same admin page. As for data validation, I don't see what there is to validate in the first place. It's just a string - not an email, address or the like that needs to be checked against a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

As in Johannes answer [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) is pretty much all you need as far as data validation. [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) has a great blog post on adding custom user meta fields.  Just add the function that outputs the form on your new admin page.